# Rosinstall: multiple ros stacks error

Tags: ros, stacks, multiple, rosws, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just trying to create a new ROS workspace on a computer in our University network using rosws init but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ rosws init . /opt/ros/fuerte/
Using ROS_ROOT: /opt/ros/fuerte/
Writing /usr/wiss/kargm/work/ros/.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /usr/wiss/kargm/work/ros
ERROR in rosinstall: Multiple ros stacks found in config set(['/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros', '/work/ros/fuerte/share/ros']), Please elimate all but one.
They come from the following sources: {'/opt/ros/fuerte/setup.sh': '/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros', '/work/ros/fuerte/share/ros': '/work/ros/fuerte/share/ros'}
```

Apparently the problem is that in our case the /opt/ros/fuerte links to /work/ros/fuerte which is a standard configuration on the university machines to save space on the system partition. Anyhow I am wondering why rosinstall is complaining about a second ros stack on /work/ros/fuerte since I could not find any reference to it in any .rosinstall-file or any other files in the ROS workspacs... So how is this "config set" (which is mentioned in the error message) build? And how can I eliminate one of the ros stacks (preferably while keeping my current setting)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47475/rosinstall:-multiple-ros-stacks-error/) by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just analyzed the problem with our administrator and it turns out that rosws seems to have a bug related to /opt/ros being a symbolic link pointing to /work/ros. Filed here: https://github.com/vcstools/rosinstall/issues/22

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1